# What is the difference between BRAM and distributed RAM

Tags: fpga, ram, dram, bram

I am doing a project on BRAM implementation. What is the difference between Block RAM and Distributed RAM on FPGA in terms of implementation, area, speed etc? Which is better?

Comment: This is really covered extensively in a lot of random places on the internet (and FPGA datasheets). Did you have a look prior to posting?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please realise this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it, showing your work and findings so far in considerable detail. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: I read much online finding the differencees. But I am unable to understand better, especially which one is better in area and speed. Also when some one says RAM is implemented in FPGA, is it done with BRAMs or anything else?

Comment: "DRAM" canonically stands for "dynamic RAM", and that's an unrelated thing, so to avoid confusion I expanded that abbreviation in your title.

Answer (score 5):

Block Ram is a dedicated Ram that does not consume any additional LUT in your design whereas distributed Ram is built up with LUT. 
In terms of speed the distributed RAM is faster than Block Rams. 
Generally speaking, if not much Ram is needed you can consider to implement it as a distributed Ram. Some synthesizers may even use distributed Ram if you specifically chose Block Ram but just use a very small amount of a single block.
As soon as you have large Ram blocks it doesn't make much sense to use distributed Ram.